# How to find the PID(s) of a hung app in macOS from the shell (Terminal)?

Tags: command-line, bash, zsh

Within `Activity Monitor.app` it's easy to visually identify a hung app by seeing its name  in red text:
[image: red text]
How can such hung app statuses be identified from the shell (`Terminal.app`) and the PID(s) of such processes retrieved?

---

UPDATE (The answer below linked to a great post, but doesn't yet contain the entire answer):

First step appears to be to identify the hung process by using `spindump`:

```
sudo spindump -notarget 5  -timelimit 60 -stdout -noFile -noProcessingWhileSampling   -aggregateStacksByProcess | grep -B 8 "Unresponsive for"
```

I will now need to extract out the PID (probably trivial) and this should do it. It would be nice if there were a more effective method... ie, it would be nice if we could discover how `Activity Monitor` itself is really doing this so quickly / effectively...

Answer (score 1):

This is actually not straightforward to do, but other people have run into this and written codes you could use. See [here](https://superuser.com/questions/798905/finding-all-not-responding-tasks-from-the-command-line-in-mac-os-x).

Comment: This is definitely a step in the right direction. I'm going to have to work on this a bit further once I have some time to both reproduce a particular hang and then to parse out the PIDs from the output of `sudo spindump -notarget 5  -timelimit 60 -stdout -noFile  -noProcessingWhileSampling   -aggregateStacksByProcess | grep -B 8 "Unresponsive for"`